# Laravel Elasticquent : How to synchronize mysql table's data to Elasticsearch?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, elasticsearch

I am using this laravel package,"Elasticquent"(https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent),

my question is,
how to synchronize mysql table's data to Elasticsearch?
For example,there is a mysql table named "articles",if some new articles are added in,how to synchronize them to Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Logstash *https://www.elastic.co/downloads/logstash*

But If its important to synchronize in time and you want to use Elasticquent you yo can use

`articles::addAllToIndex();`

Next you can write **customize** query and use for example

```
$articles = articles::where('created_at', '<', <yourFormat>)->get();
$articles->addToIndex();
```

**in your admin server jobs to run it in any time you want index your data**
*https://github.com/elasticquent/Elasticquent#indexing-documents*

Answer (score -1):

Check this presentation out from Laracon EU (https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=waTWeJeFp4A) to get you started. Some good tips there, especially with the model events for synching new data.

Easy to use Laravel package to work with elasticsearch. More info here: https://murze.be/2015/01/using-elasticsearch-in-laravel/

Hopefully it will help you to understand process of sync data.